# How do I download Vista hotfixes since SP2 for a vLite image?

Tags: windows, windows-vista, updates, sp2, vlite

I am creating an up to date Vista image with vLite. Therefore I integrated SP2 in the slipstream, but the SP2 came out in May 26, 2009, according to Microsoft. There has been numerous hotfixes released since then.

How can I download them?

Comment: Duplicated on SF - http://serverfault.com/questions/67136/how-do-i-download-vista-hotfixes-since-sp2-for-a-vlite-image

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you may download all Windows Vista Security updates and patches released since SP2 **[here](http://softwarepatch.com/windows-vista/windows-vista-security-updates-2009.html)**.